# C# Json request won't work

Tags: c#, json, post

So basically I'm trying to send a json request into http://op.gg/mmr/ajax/mmr.json, the json would conclude {"summonerName":"DeCodux"}, but my problem is it appears like this code doesn't send anything into the mmr.json in on their webservers.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://op.gg/mmr/ajax/mmr.json");
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                    {
                        summonerName = "DeCodux"
                    });

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();

                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        DataBox.Text = result;
                    }
                }
```

Neither will this piece of code;

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://op.gg/mmr/ajax/mmr.json/");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Host = "op.gg";
                request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
                request.Referer = "http://op.gg/mmr/region=EUW";
                //request.ContentLength = 27;
                //request.Connection = "keep-alive";
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string writeit = "{\"summonerName\":\"DeCodux\"}";

                // string writethis = "{\"region\"=\"EUW\"," + "\"userName\"=\"DeCodux\"}";
                    writer.Write(writeit);


                }

                var response = request.GetResponse();
                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var json = "";

                if (stream == null) return;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                 {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        json += reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                #endregion oldtest
                /* var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var x = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
                MyData data = serializer.Deserialize<MyData>(x.ToString());*/
               /* var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var data = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
                */
                DataBox.Text = json;
```

I just commented out the serialization and Dictionary parts, since those I'll be able to handle easily. Also, when I retrieve the raw response from the servers now, I get:

```
{"error":true,"errormsg":"\uc18c\ud658\uc0ac\uba85\uc744 \uc785\ub825\ud574\uc8fc\uc138\uc694."}
```

Which parsed and translated is

```
{
"error": true,
"errormsg": "Please enter the name of the Summoner." }
```

So since it gives me that error as a response, it seems like my json request didn't send into their server. If the request would be sent but it would be incorrect, it would give me other errors like "This summoner does not ---" and so on. Also I went trough all the post request headers etc. with firebug "net" mode.

So my question is, what's gone wrong here? Why does it not send the POST request?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Are you certain you have `summonerName` in the case and spelling expected by the host?

Comment: Yeah, I'm certain. Checked tens of times with firebug, you can try it yourself by going to op.gg/mrr, inputting any name you want and press "Get mmr" then check the net tab from firebug.